# Enviar valor de checkbox PHP

Tags: php

Eu posso usar o mesmo name="" em dois inputs do tipo checkbox para fazer uma validação em PHP?

Por exemplo, eu quero pegar o valor da checkbox marcada e fazer uma validação, porém não está pegando valor nenhum.

```
<input id="add-festa-k" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="tipoFesta" value="1499" />
<label for="add-festa-k">Festa 1</label>

<input id="add-festa-k" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="tipoFesta" value="2000" />
<label for="add-festa-k">Festa 2</label>


<?php

$tipoFesta = $_POST['tipoFesta'];

if($tipoFesta >= 2000){
    $tipoFesta = 'Festa 2';
}else{
    $tipoFesta = 'Festa 1';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue abaixo como deve ficar o seu código, sabendo das suas necessidades o que me parece mais conveniente seria colocá-los em um array, por isso juntei a resposta do [Diego](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17091/diego) com a minha, ficando:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input id="add-festa-k" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="tipoFesta[]" value="1499" />
<label for="add-festa-k">Festa 1</label>
<input id="add-festa-k" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="tipoFesta[]" value="2000" />
<label for="add-festa-k">Festa 2</label>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

<?php

$tipoFesta = array_filter($_POST['tipoFesta']);

foreach($tipoFesta as $key => $tipoFesta){
  if($tipoFesta == 2000){
      $tipoFesta = 'Festa 2 - Valor de R$2.000,00';
      echo "<br>". $tipoFesta;
}else{
  $tipoFesta = 'Festa 1 - Valor de R$1.499,00';
  echo "<br>". $tipoFesta;
};
}

?>
```

Comment: Eu só postei um pedaço do código, e sim estou usando form e o method= post. Não posso usar o radio devido a funções da minha aplicação...

Comment: Entendi, mas você consegue usar o checkbox normalmente, não vejo problemas, mas qual o seu objetivo por exemplo, se o usuário clicar nas duas festar e dar um submit? Só para entender melhor.

Comment: Quando o usuário preencher todos os campos, eu preciso pegar o valor do checkbox e fazer uma comparação, se o checkbox marcado tiver o value="2000" então o que vai escrito no e-mail vai ser Festa 2

Comment: Entendi, alterei o código, como a alternativa seja mesmo um array, juntei o meu código com o do @Diego. Veja se é assim que queria.

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma:

- No HTML altere o nome para um array:

  `name='tipoFesta[]'`
- NO PHP trate o array para ignorar eventuais campos em branco:

  `array_filter($_POST['tipoFesta']);`
- Faça um `foreach` e dentro dele faça a validação:

  ```
  foreach ($tipoFesta_in as $key => $tipoFesta) {  
        // FAÇA AS> VALIDAÇÕES USANDO $tipoFesta[$key]    
   }
  ```

Comment: o que seria esse $key?

Comment: É o 'passo' do array. Tem a quantidade de campos com esse nome no html.